About customizing the email address where notifications are sent from GCP
In a project we manage, maintenance notifications have been sent to only certain members.
I would like everyone in my group to receive the same email, how can I do that?

Not nearly enough info. Which os, which software, hosted or local, how to access - exchange, pop3, imap? Basically, you create a group, add members to it, then send the email to it. Alternatively, create a new user, grant everyone permission to its mailbox, and send email to it.
